# Putting MINUTES in the Max Attribute on a Progress Element

Tags: angular, audio, progress

So I have a songDuration variable:

for example:

```
this.songDuration = 4:20
```

I am using angular 4, so I am using interpolation to input the value

```
<progress value="{{songTime}}" max="{{songDuration}}"></progress>
```

when I do this, I get the error message "The provided double value is non-finite" in the console.

How could I convert this variable to a value that would be compatible with the max attribute?

Comment: I don't understand how you're even getting past the line "this.songDuration = 4:20". That's not valid JavaScript or TypeScript. You'd have to change that to something like 4.3333333.

Comment: its written like that as a string in the json instead of a number so im glad you mentioned that. thank you. now i have to convert them all to seconds noooooo lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
convert(input) {
    var parts = input.split(':'),
    minutes = +parts[0],
    seconds = +parts[1];
    return (minutes * 60 + seconds).toFixed(3);
}
```

Then

```
this.songDuration = this.convert('4:20');
this.songTime = this.convert('<something else>');
```

(comment if there was any problem)